# Joining two tables of data with no unique identifier

Tags: sql, python-3.x, join

I have two tables with no unique identifier. Here is what it looks like:

```
Table 1 -
case_id   Family_Number   Family_Description
101       FG55            Camellia_14_Pro
203       FOAF            DVD Tracker
509       FAD6            Laserjet Printer X100

Table 2 -
Family_Number    Family_Description   GoG_Description    Hierarchy_Level
FG55             Camellia_14_Pro      Computron_14       2
FG55             Camellia_14_Pro      Canary_14          3
FG55             Camellia_14_Pro      Delta_14           4
FG55             Camellia_14_Pro      Camellia_14        0
```

I want to join these tables so that every case_id can identify with it's unique hierarchy_level. I have tried inner, outer, left and right joins but I am not getting the required result. It just identified some random hierarchy level for all cases. I tried doing cross join and union but even that didn't work as it gives null values for hierarchy level.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please format your tables so that they are readable and also provide the result you expect to see based on your source data

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Is your problem that there is no case_id in table2? There is Family_Number + Family_Description instead that you can use for the join. But "every case_id can identify with it's unique hierarchy_level"? It seems that there is no unique hierarchy_level per case_id. Aren't there four different hierarchy_level for case_id 101 you are showing? Or am I misinterpreting your tables? To me it looks like you simply want to join the tables and sort by case_id and hierarchy_level. Please add sample data for other case_id and show the expected result.